# Overwriting files upon install on MAC OSX

Tags: macos, installation

Ive written a piece of software that requires users to install/overwrite some files/folders on a MAC.

They're having major problems with the fact that OSX asks you to "keep both", sometimes "keep newer", or even "merge" in the overwriting dialogue.

Depending on the OSX version the message can change.

Is there any way I can write a program that installs these files automatically? Overwriting certain files that exist already?

It's a complete headache for the user and I would love to find an answer to this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an installer package for your software. It's usually the most straight forward method to get the right files where they need to be — and it's the accepted way of doing it.

See:

- [**pkgbuild**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html)
- [**productbuild**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html)

Comment: Just wondering, will it let me overwrite files and delete files that already exist on the users computer?

Comment: Yes, installer packages generally use administrator permissions which allow you to target files exactly where needed. So for example lets say you had an application that needed to be placed into `/Application` and a plugin that goes into `~/Library/Plugins` — the installer would copy the files (or overwrite them if they existed) into/at those locations.